# Can't figure out why this OpenGL program is not rendering

Tags: opengl

I compiled [Joe Groff's "An intro to modern OpenGL: Hello World: The Slideshow](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Chapter-2%3a-Hello-World%3a-The-Slideshow.html).
I have compiled it using Mingw-w64 with freeglut, Glut 3.7 and a version that makes my own context.

However, when I run the program, the image doesn't fade back and forth like its supposed to and I can't figure out why (spent a whole day on it).

Also, I have examined most of inputs and outputs except for the shaders and cant find anything wrong, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you take the exact same code? https://github.com/jckarter/hello-gl Any OpenGL errors?

Comment: @Bart: Yeah, the exact same code, and I also called `glGetError()` at the end of `render()` and didnt get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your OpenGL version doesn't support shaders.  Are you by any chance running in a virtual machine or via remote desktop?  These tend to only support OpenGL 1.1 even if the graphics card/drivers are much more recent, and OpenGL 1.1 does not support shaders.  It's also possible that if you're using an older laptop with an integrated Intel GPU that shaders are not (properly) supported.

Comment: I am using an Intel GPU, however `glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION_ARB);` is giving me 1.20, which led me to believe I would be okay.

Comment: After searching around the internet, it seems that the version numbers can't be trusted. I will accept this as the answer because it seems to be the only plausible cause. If you know a way to verify whether the shaders are working or not, please let me know. Thanks.